# Prove that the order of an element in a cyclic group must divide the order of the group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is it possible to prove this without invoking Lagrange's Theorem? Using it, the proof becomes trivially easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume 
$$
x^{k}=e
$$

and write
$$
k=qn+r
$$

with $0\leq r<n$ (We can do this with the Euclidean Algorithm) then
$$
e=x^{k}=(x^{n})^{q}\cdot x^{r}=x^{r}
$$

and thus $r=0$, so $k=qn$ i.e $n|k$

Answer (score 4):

Let he order of the group be $n$ since the group is cyclic we can assume it is of the form $g^k$, we then need to find the smallest value $l$ so that $(g^k)^l=1$ notice this is $g^{kl}=1$. This only happens if $n$ divides $kl$ by how the cyclic subgroup works.

Therefore we need to find the smallest postive $l$ so that $n|kl$ this is clearly going to be a divisor of $n$ since otherwise we could take away some unecessary primes from $l$ to make it into $l'$ so that $kl'$ is still a multiple of $n$ but is smaller.

Comment: Could you further eloborate what you mean by "This only happens if $n$ divides $kl$ by how the cyclic subgroup works"? Is there a specific property of subgroups you are referring to?

Comment: It seems that you are using that you want to prove

Comment: How am I using what I want to prove? All I am saying is if $x^j=1$ then $n|j$. you can prove this in many ways, one such way is contradiction via euclidean algorithm.